# How to have profiles list while I open Bitvise SSH client

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys, bitvise

I have newly installed Bitvise SSH client and cant find a very simple feature to save/open profile inside program. It seems that it saves profiles in external files so as every time I open the client i have to browse for profile file...

Can it be made as it's putty, so when I open putty, there is straightforward list of the profile on which i have just double click. I am a bit surprised.

Comment: Use the command line parameter `-profile=xxx` - the profile to open on startup.

Comment: @DavidPostill  that suggested method (i've seen on their site) i have to create tens of shortcuts to target the desired connection?  it is no way near to putty simplicity - just a click in list to open.